# jQuery UI widgets in TypeScript

Tags: jquery-ui, typescript

I am using a jQuery UI slider in a TypeScript application, using TypeScript 0.9 and the latest `jqueryui.d.ts` definition file downloaded from DefinitelyTyped:

```
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts" />

. . .

$("#sideRestitution").slider({
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  step: 0.01,
  value: game.sideRestitution,
  change: (event, ui) => {
    game.sideRestitution = ui.value;
  }
});
```

It works fine, but I cannot figure out how to use the widget in a 'typed' way: in the above code `change` is of type `any`. `jqueryui.d.ts` defines a `Slider` interface with the events and methods specific to the slider widget, but the only method or property returning such an interface is the global `$.ui.slider`.

How do I access / use the `Slider` interface for a slider widget I created?

What is the use/purpose of `$.ui.slider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of `jqueryui.d.ts` there is no way to define the widget events in a 'typed` way.

The globals `$.ui.slider`, `$.ui.accordion` etc. are used as base to define new widgets - e.g:

```
$.widget("ui.myslider", $.ui.slider, { . . . });
```

creates a new `myslider` widget that extends the built-in slider widget. These globals are used also to access the prototype of each widget, for example to modify their default options:

```
$.ui.slider.prototyp.options.min = -100;
```

modifies the default minimum value of all sliders to be `-100`.

The definition of these globals in `jqueryui.d.ts` appears to be wrong: it does not define `prototype` and instead defines a number of other members - like all the options - that are actually not there.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to include `jquery.d.ts` in order to access and manipulate typed jQuery objects. This will allow you to access your slider in the typical jQuery way. For example:

```js
/* Initialize slider with ID 'my_slider'. */
$("#my_slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    change: (event: Event, ui) => {   
        /* Update as desired. */
    }
});
```

In this example, the type for `$('#my_slider')` is defined in `jquery.d.ts`, and all the relevant slider functions and such are defined in `jqueryui.d.ts`.

Just to finish off the example, in your HTML, you'll want something like:

```html
<div id="my_slider"></div>
```

EDIT: I think this is a bug. Even with the following:

```js
var my_slider : JQueryUI.Slider = $('#my_slider').slider;
my_slider.slide({
  ...
})
```

It still doesn't register the type information for `slide`.

**Here's a hack-ish fix**. Replace the `SliderUIParams` interface (line 442 in `jqueryui.d.ts`) with an actual interface:

```js
interface SliderUIParams {
  value: number;
  values?: number[];
  handle: JQuery;
}
```

Then, in your slider call, statically type your arugments, e.g.:

```js
slide: (event: Event, ui: JQueryUI.SliderUIParams) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are suggesting - but in this way `change` does not have a type, nor the call-back parameters `event` and `ui`, whereas `jqueryui.d.ts` declares both the `SliderEvent` interface and the `change` property - but I don't know how to access these declarations.

Comment: Yes, I am. As I wrote I have code exactly as you wrote - and it works - but there is no type checking (try to set `change` to a number: no compiler error).

Comment: Interesting. I'll investigate further. I have similar code in my project and I too have argument types `any`.

Comment: There actually doesn't seem like a great way to do this. If you look at the definitions file (line 442), `ui` is of type `SliderUIParams`, which is just an empty interface and isn't referenced anywhere else. So we have no type information about `ui`. What you _could_ do, if you want type information about event, is declare it as of type `Event`. See my edit above.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that you are missing my point: I know that I can add declarations in the code - but the declaration of `change` as a function with two parameters etc. already exists in `jqueryui.d.ts`, but I don't know how this declaration is supposed to be used (assuming that it has been placed there not just for fun)

Comment: No, I understand the problem. It's not recognizing the type signature of `change`, even when it recognizes the type of your slider. It's a problematic definition, in my opinion, because the `JQueryUI.SliderUIParams` interface doesn't even have any properties in `jqueryui.d.ts`. So even if it _did_ recognize the type, it wouldn't provide much value.